# How to grant bucket sync permission to role

Tags: security, buckets, role-management

I have a custom bucket that organizes items using a custom rule based on the value of a date field called "Event Start Date" on each page item.

[image: Bucket structure]

I'm trying to give content authors the ability to manually sync the bucket because items do not bucket automatically due to the "Event Start Date" field being empty when a new page is created.

This is what I can see as a super admin:

[image]

I have made our author role a member of `sitecore\Sitecore Client Bucket Management`, but all the author can see is:

[image]

It still doesn't work even when I grant specific permissions on the item in question (this is the security viewer):

[image]

As a side note, I'm not finding much information on this anywhere. Is the standard practice to auto sync buckets on save or item add events?

Comment: The sync should be automatic and transparent to the author. I would not think that they have any need to do this activity.

Comment: @MichaelWest Automatic bucket syncing? I've never seen that before -- not without custom code. Please advise.

Comment: https://www.sitecorespark.com/article/buckets my understanding of buckets is that it's a one-time setup. As items are added to the tree Sitecore handles the structure based on your bucketing rule. Sync is only needed when a configuration change occurs.

Comment: When is bucket syncing _not_ happening for you? As @MichaelWest says, the items should automatically be created in the right spot automatically.

Comment: @DanSinclair I see what you mean. I have edited the question to provide more information. The reason why it's not bucketing automatically is because I have a custom bucketing rule based on a date field on the page items themselves (in this case it's called Event Start Date).

Comment: That makes sense. See my answers below for more information and a couple solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing the code for this ribbon button (`Sitecore.Buckets.Commands.SyncBucket` in the `Sitecore.Buckets.dll`) reveals that the user must be an Administrator to have access to this button:

```
public override CommandState QueryState(CommandContext context)
{
    Error.AssertObject(context, "context");
    Item items = context.Items[0];
    BucketSecurityManager bucketSecurityManager = new BucketSecurityManager(items);
    if (items.Appearance.ReadOnly)
    {
        return CommandState.Disabled;
    }
    if (!items.Locking.HasLock() && !Context.User.IsAdministrator)
    {
        return CommandState.Disabled;
    }
    if (items.Locking.IsLocked() && !items.Locking.HasLock())
    {
        return CommandState.Disabled;
    }
    if (!bucketSecurityManager.IsAllowedToCreateBucket)
    {
        return CommandState.Disabled;
    }
    if (!items.IsBucketItemCheck())
    {
        return CommandState.Disabled;
    }
    return CommandState.Enabled;
}
```

### Next steps

You could theoretically override this behavior by creating a subclass of `SyncBucket` and overriding the `QueryState` method to evaluate your own security rules, then add a patch config to update the class used for the `item:syncbucket` command to use your custom class instead.

> Note: a better solution, however, is to automatically sync the items as they are updated (using something like [this solution](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/23654/342)), instead of requiring authors to manually click the Sync button.

### For the curious: How to find the above information?

I reviewed the security for the **Sync** button in the ribbon by following the below steps:

1. Find the ribbon button in the `core` database (`/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Item Buckets/Sync`)
2. Check its security and the security of its parent

   - Its parent's security gives access to users of roles `sitecore\Sitecore Client Configuring` and `sitecore\Sitecore Client Bucket Management`

Even after granting a user access to one of those roles, however, does not allow them to click the *Sync* button, however, so I reviewed the code:

1. The ribbon button item in the `core` database has the command name `item:syncbucket`
2. Looking at `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`, I found that it points to `Sitecore.Buckets.Commands.SyncBucket` in the `Sitecore.Buckets.dll`
3. In that class, I found the above `QueryState` method, which shows how it determines whether to enable or disable the button.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by programmatically moving the bucketed item to the root of the bucket with the `BucketManager`. Doing this will force it to reevaluate the bucket rules and reorganize it:

```
BucketManager.MoveItemIntoBucket(bucketedItem, bucketItem);
```

Note that this is different from `BucketManager.Sync(bucketItem)` because it does not sync the *whole* bucket, but instead handles just the single item that was changed.

In our solutions, we typically create an `item:saved` event handler to do this automatically:

```
using Sitecore.Buckets.Managers;
using Sitecore.Buckets.Util;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Events;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Custom.Events.ItemSaved
{
    public class ReorganizeBucketedItemInBucket
    {
        public void OnItemSaved(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            var bucketedItem = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;

            // If we don't have an item or we're not saving in the master DB, ignore this save
            if (bucketedItem == null || !"master".Equals(bucketedItem.Database?.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                return;

            if (!bucketedItem.TemplateID.Equals(new ID("{bucketed-item-template-id}"))) return;

            var itemChanges = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 1) as ItemChanges;

            // If there were no changes or the changes didn't include the date field, ignore this save
            if (itemChanges == null || !itemChanges.HasFieldsChanged || !itemChanges.IsFieldModified(new ID("{field-id-of-date-field}")))
                return;

            Item bucketItem = bucketedItem.Axes.SelectSingleItem($"{EscapePath(bucketedItem.Paths.FullPath)}/ancestor-or-self::*[@@templateid = '{{bucket-container-template-id}}']");

            // If this item isn't in a bucket (or is in a bucket of another, unexpected type), ignore it
            if (bucketItem == null) return;

            Item parent = bucketedItem.Parent;
            BucketManager.MoveItemIntoBucket(bucketedItem, bucketItem);

            // Delete empty ancestor bucket folders
            while (parent != null && !parent.HasChildren && parent.TemplateID == BucketConfigurationSettings.BucketTemplateId)
            {
                Item tempParent = parent.Parent;
                parent.Delete();
                parent = tempParent;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Wraps each segment of a sitecore path with "#"'s
        /// </summary>
        public string EscapePath(string path)
        {
            return Regex.Replace(path, @"([^/]+)", "#$1#").Replace("#*#", "*");
        }
    }
}
```

And don't forget your patch config, of course:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <events>
            <event name="item:saved">
                <handler type="Custom.Events.ItemSaved.ReorganizeBucketedItemInBucket, Custom.Events" method="OnItemSaved"></handler>
            </event>
        </events>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```